# Multiple definition error building RInside samples on Windows 7 x64

Tags: r, rcpp, rinside

I'm trying to build rinside_sample1.cpp from RInside\examples\standard directory on Windows 7 x64 using g++ from RTools in the following way:

```
set RCPP=%R_HOME%\library\Rcpp
set RINSIDE=%R_HOME%\library\RInside
g++ -c -m64 rinside_sample1.cpp -I %RINSIDE%\include -I %RCPP%\include -I %R_HOME%\include
g++ -m64 rinside_sample1.o -o rinside_sample1.exe -L %RINSIDE%\libs\x64 -l RInside -L %RCPP%\libs\x64 -l Rcpp -L %R_HOME%\bin\x64 -l R
```

The linkage results into the multiple definition error:

```
d000026.o:(.idata$5+0x0): multiple definition of `__imp__ZTVN4Rcpp7RObjectE'
d000019.o:(.idata$5+0x0): first defined here
d000026.o:(.idata$6+0x0): multiple definition of `__nm__ZTVN4Rcpp7RObjectE'
d000019.o:(.idata$6+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**However the similar building process for rinside_sample0.cpp succeedes. Does anyone have an idea of the solution?**

It seems that the problem with rinside_sample1.cpp arises because of Rcpp::NumericMatrix and Rcpp::NumericVector usage.

rinside_sample0.cpp code:

```
// -*- mode: C++; c-indent-level: 4; c-basic-offset: 4;  tab-width: 8; -*-
//
// Simple example showing how to do the standard 'hello, world' using embedded R
//
// Copyright (C) 2009 Dirk Eddelbuettel 
// Copyright (C) 2010 Dirk Eddelbuettel and Romain Francois
//
// GPL'ed 

#include <RInside.h>                    // for the embedded R via RInside

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    RInside R(argc, argv);              // create an embedded R instance 

    R["txt"] = "Hello, world!\n";   // assign a char* (string) to 'txt'

    R.parseEvalQ("cat(txt)");           // eval the init string, ignoring any returns

    exit(0);
}
```

rinside_sample1.cpp code:

```
// -*- mode: C++; c-indent-level: 4; c-basic-offset: 4; tab-width: 8; -*-
//
// Simple example with data in C++ that is passed to R, processed and a result is extracted
//
// Copyright (C) 2009         Dirk Eddelbuettel 
// Copyright (C) 2010 - 2011  Dirk Eddelbuettel and Romain Francois
//
// GPL'ed 

#include <RInside.h>                            // for the embedded R via RInside

Rcpp::NumericMatrix createMatrix(const int n) {
    Rcpp::NumericMatrix M(n,n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            M(i,j) = i*10 + j; 
        }
    }
    return(M);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    RInside R(argc, argv);                      // create an embedded R instance 

    const int mdim = 4;                         // let the matrices be 4 by 4; create, fill 
    R["M"] = createMatrix(mdim);                // then assign data Matrix to R's 'M' var

    std::string str = 
        "cat('Running ls()\n'); print(ls()); "
        "cat('Showing M\n'); print(M); "
        "cat('Showing colSums()\n'); Z <- colSums(M); print(Z); "
        "Z";                     // returns Z


    Rcpp::NumericVector v = R.parseEval(str);   // eval string, Z then assigned to num. vec              

    for (int i=0; i< v.size(); i++) {           // show the result
        std::cout << "In C++ element " << i << " is " << v[i] << std::endl;
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you do not use the Makefile I supplied and which works?  Just say

```
 make rinside_sample1
```

which, on my machine, leads to

```
edd@max:~/svn/rinside/pkg/inst/examples/standard$ make rinside_sample1
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include \
   -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/include -O3 -pipe -g -Wall  \
   rinside_sample1.cpp  -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR  -lblas -llapack \
   -L/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/lib \
   -lRcpp -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/lib \
   -L/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/lib \
   -lRInside -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/lib \
   -o rinside_sample1
edd@max:~/svn/rinside/pkg/inst/examples/standard$
```

after which we can do

```
edd@max:~/svn/rinside/pkg/inst/examples/standard$ ./rinside_sample1
Running ls()
[1] "argv" "M"   
Showing M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    2    3
[2,]   10   11   12   13
[3,]   20   21   22   23
[4,]   30   31   32   33
Showing colSums()
[1] 60 64 68 72
In C++ element 0 is 60
In C++ element 1 is 64
In C++ element 2 is 68
In C++ element 3 is 72
edd@max:~/svn/rinside/pkg/inst/examples/standard$
```

It works the same on Windows, but you need to do

```
make -f Makefile.win rinside_sample1
```

Comment: As I use x64 version I have uncommented `R_ARCH := --arch x64` line in Makefile.win. Unfortunately that produces the incorrect value for `RINSIDELIBS` and I get `g++ -m64 -IC:/R/R-2.15.1/include -IC:/R/R-2.15.1/include/x64 -IC:/R/R-2.15.1/library/Rcpp/include -IC:/R/R-2.15.1/library/RInside/include -O2 -Wall -mtune=core2 -Wall  -s  rinside_sample3.cpp  -LC:/R/R-2.15.1/bin/x64 -lR -LC:/R/R-2.15.1/bin/x64 -lRblas -LC:/R/R-2.15.1/bin/x64 -lRlapack "/libRInside.a" C:/R/R-2.15.1/library/Rcpp/lib/x64/libRcpp.a -o rinside_sample1
g++.exe: error: /libRInside.a: No such file or directory`.

Comment: There is no such a problem in `R_ARCH := --arch i386` case. However the proper build command for x64 is clear now - thanks for help!

Comment: I was under the impression that the current R and the current Rtools for Windows seamlessly build for 32 and 64 bit.